# How I can remove the new google Play service and use the previous one?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I´m having a lot of problems with the new Google Play Services version (17) and the push notifications.
Could I remove it and use the previous one version on my current project?
Thanks

Comment: yES you cant if you want

Comment: Thanks @sakir!! How I can do it?

Comment: Remove that from SDK Manager and Install new